# How to convert the double value to string without losing the data in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, tostring

I have a double value as below

```
double propertyValue = 1994.7755474452554;
```

When i convert this double value to a string

```
string value = propertyValue.ToString();
```

it gives the value  `"1994.77554744526"`

It has *rounded off* the last digits `2554` to `26`.

But I do not want to round the value. Share your ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the .ToString() method of Double returns 15 digits of precision. If you want the full 17 digits that the double value holds internally, you need to pass the "G17" format specifier to the method.

```
String s = value.ToString("G17");
```

This will prevent the rounding off of double value when converted to string.

```
value = propertyValue.ToString("G17");
```

Comment: This [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) describes it.

Comment: Hi ViVi, If the propertyValue type is "Object". means, object propertyValue = 1994.7755474452554; value = propertyValue.ToString("G17"); throws an error [no overload for method “ToString” takes 1 arguments]

Comment: @Kalai That means the object property can only be converted to string according to the preset rules. It doesn't have precision correction like we did in `double.tostring("G17")`. Double is expected to have precision correction. But why do you need it to be an object, when the default type for it is double? '

Answer (score 1):

You could use decimal type instead.

```
decimal propertyValue = 1994.7755474452554M;
```

Answer (score 1):

I *can't reproduce* the misbehaviour; you've experienced a representation effect: it's `ToString()` puts `double` like that.

```
  string source = "1994.7755474452554";

  double d = double.Parse(source, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  string test = d.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  Console.Write(source.Equals(test) ? "OK" : "Rounded !!!");
```

Outcome is `OK`. Please, notice `"R"` format string:

> The Round-trip ("R") Format Specifier

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#RFormatString

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `double` to `decimal` and use the default `ToString()` like this:

```
Double propertyValue = 1994.77554744526;
var str = ((decimal)propertyValue).ToString();
//str will hold 1994.77554744526
```